# Init Method not showing up in Swift Bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

The following class with the Swift initializer

```
  public init(aTracker : SessionTracker , aRater : RatingInfo)
{
    self.tracker = aTracker
    self.rater = aRater
    super.init()
}
```

This initializer isn't there in the Swift bridging header but all the other methods are present. So I can't instantiate this class from Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by making the parameters of the initializer optionals :

```
   public init(tracker : SessionTracker? , aRater : RatingInfo?)
    {
        self.tracker = tracker!
        self.rater = aRater!
        super.init()
    }
```

This makes sense as Objective-C can't ensure that the params are non nil.

Comment: You should also be able to make the parameters Unwrapped Optionals so you dont have to put the ! when assigning.

Comment: Reason is that from Obj-C all objects are optionals while Swift does separate them. If the version from your question would be available from Obj-C then the Obj-C method coud sucessfully pass null ending up for you with a non-optional containing nil plus all subsequent issues.